# .htaccess re-write use a get variable to replace the filename

Tags: php, asp.net, .htaccess

This one is a bit tricky for me, I want to make this URL as minimal as possible. Ideally I would like to change this URL:

http://www.example.co.uk/profile/profile.asp?profile_id=1&top=1&abt=2&ft=3&school=Something%20School

to:

http://www.example.co.uk/something-school/

Using .htaccess file.

This means we would be using the school get variable to replace the .asp file name, getting rid of /profile/ as well as the other get variables.

Is this possible? If so how? If not could you potentially give me an alternative?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

A user Badhorsie has wrote a rewrite rule for me which does the exact conversion. Unfortunately the webpage fails to load as these get variables are unfortunately necessary for the page to load.

I am guessing it is not possible to hide the get variables. In which case would it be possible to retain the get variables but to keep them clean? Looks like the directory is also necessary?

Perhaps something like: www.example.co.uk/profile/something-school/1/1/2/3

We can get rid of the school get variable as it is not needed (only needed to replace the profile/profile.asp section.

Comment: .htaccess is linked to an apache server, since your file type is `.asp` I assume you have an ASP.NET server

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Hi Rasmus, we do have a module installed on the server which interprets .htaccess files so should not be an issue.

Comment: Starkeen - honestly with this one I don't know where to start as there is too much going on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+(?=&school))school=([\w%-]+)
RewriteRule ^profile/profile.asp /%2?%1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this generated: http://www.example.co.uk/Example%2520School?profile_id=1&top=1&abt=2&ft=3&school=Example%2520School which isn't working.

Comment: @Aasim Sorry, try now. I fixed it.

Comment: Hi Badhorsie, it does do the rewrite correctly but the page fails to load. I am assuming it is because the re-write doesn't retain the get variables. In which case can we retain these except for the school variable.

Comment: @Aasim Answer edited again. Try it, I haven't tested it.

Comment: Hi BadHorsie, unfortunately the client changed his mind about this. That's clients for you! But with that said I must say you knew very well what you was doing so I'll mark your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this RewriteRule. Try adding this code in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule   ^http://www.example.co.uk/profile/profile.asp?profile_id=1&top=1&abt=2&ft=3&school=Something%20School?$ http://www.example.co.uk/something-school/ [L]
```

Comment: It needs to be dynamic